# Exporting to text file from google sheet in loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I need someone to help me on how i can export from selected google sheet cells to a text file with a new line on each cells value.
I'm a just a beginner in this GoogleApp script. The code that i was wrote:

```
function createGoogleDriveTextFile() {
var content1,content2,fileName,newFile;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TabulateData');

fileName = "Mydatelist.txt";
for (var j=4;j< 10 ; ++j){
  content1 = ss.getRange(j,22).getValue()
  content2 = "Date 1: " + content1 ;
}
newFile = DriveApp.createFile(fileName,content2);//Create a new text file in the root folder
}
```

But the output from this code only showing me the last value of the cells & not the entire cells value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "V4:V9" in the sheet of "TabulateData".
- You want to export the retrieved values by putting the line break for each row.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

### Modification points:

- In your script, in the for loop, `content2` is overwritten every loop. I think that this is the reason of your issue of `the output from this code only showing me the last value of the cells & not the entire cells value.`.
- And, in your script, the line break is not included.

### Modification pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified.

#### From:

```
for (var j=4;j< 10 ; ++j){
  content1 = ss.getRange(j,22).getValue()
  content2 = "Date 1: " + content1 ;
}
```

#### To:

```
for (var j=4;j< 10 ; ++j){
  content1 = ss.getRange(j,22).getValue();
  content2 += "Date 1: " + content1 + "\n";  // Modified
}
```

### Modification pattern 2:

In this pattern, your script is modified by reducing the process cost. Because `getValue()` is used in the loop, the process cost will be high.

#### From:

```
for (var j=4;j< 10 ; ++j){
  content1 = ss.getRange(j,22).getValue()
  content2 = "Date 1: " + content1 ;
}
```

#### To:

```
var content2 = ss
  .getRange("V4:V9")
  .getValues()
  .map(([v]) => `Date 1: ${v}`)
  .join("\n");
```

### Note:

- When you use the pattern 2, please enable V8 runtime.

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)